# Using java to count spaces in a sentence but only returns initial value

Tags: java, methods, char

I tried to write  code to count words of a sentence(actually counting the space in-between a sentence). But it always returns 1(initial value). Do you have any idea? Thank you!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CountingWords22
{

public static int countWords(String str)
{
    int count = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (ch == ' ')
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main()
{   System.out.println("enter your words");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String test = input.next();
    System.out.println(test + " has " + countWords(test) + " words." );
}

}
```

Comment: `Scanner.next()` reads until the first space, ie. one word. You probably want `nextLine`.

Comment: Yes. There will never be a String accessed with `Scanner.next()` that contains a `" "`.

Comment: thank you so much!! it works!!